# How to optimize the memory usage of my python crawler

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-crawler

I am learning python crawler these days, and I write a simple crawler to get the picture on the [Pixiv](http://www.pixiv.net/) by Pixiv ID.

It works quite well, but here comes a big problem: When it is running, it takes up nearly 1.2G memory on my computer.

However, sometimes it just takes up just 10M memory, I really don't know which code causes such big usage of memory.

I have uploaded the script to my VPS(Only 768M memory Vulter server) and tried to run. As a result, I get a MerroyError.

So I wonder how to optimize the memory usage(even if taking more time to run).

Here is my code:

(I have rewrote all the code to make it pass `pep8`, if still unclear, please tell me which code makes you confused.)

```
from lxml import etree
import re
import os
import requests


# Get a single Picture.
def get_single(Pixiv_ID, Tag_img_src, Headers):
    Filter_Server = re.compile("[\d]+")
    Filter_Posttime = re.compile("img\/[^_]*_p0")
    Posttime = Filter_Posttime.findall(Tag_img_src)[0]
    Server = Filter_Server.findall(Tag_img_src)[0]
    Picture_Type = [".png", ".jpg", ".gif"]
    for i in range(len(Picture_Type)):
        Original_URL = "http://i" + str(Server) + ".pixiv.net/img-original/"\
                       + Posttime+Picture_Type[i]
        Picture = requests.get(Original_URL, headers=Headers, stream=True)
        if Picture.status_code == 200:
            break
    if Picture.status_code != 200:
        return -1
    Filename = "./pic/"\
               + str(Pixiv_ID) + "_p0"\
               + Picture_Type[i]
    Picture_File = open(Filename, "wb+")
    for chunk in Picture.iter_content(None):
        Picture_File.write(chunk)
    Picture_File.close()
    Picture.close()
    return 200


# Get manga which is a bundle of pictures.
def get_manga(Pixiv_ID, Tag_a_href, Tag_img_src, Headers):
    os.mkdir("./pic/" + str(Pixiv_ID))
    Filter_Server = re.compile("[\d]+")
    Filter_Posttime = re.compile("img\/[^_]*_p")
    Manga_URL = "http://www.pixiv.net/"+Tag_a_href
    Manga_HTML = requests.get(Manga_URL, headers=Headers)
    Manga_XML = etree.HTML(Manga_HTML.content)
    Manga_Pages = Manga_XML.xpath('/html/body'
                                  '/nav[@class="page-menu"]'
                                  '/div[@class="page"]'
                                  '/span[@class="total"]/text()')[0]
    Posttime = Filter_Posttime.findall(Tag_img_src)[0]
    Server = Filter_Server.findall(Tag_img_src)[0]
    Manga_HTML.close()
    Picture_Type = [".png", ".jpg", ".gif"]
    for Number in range(int(Manga_Pages)):
        for i in range(len(Picture_Type)):
            Original_URL = "http://i" + str(Server) + \
                           ".pixiv.net/img-original/"\
                           + Posttime + str(Number) + Picture_Type[i]
            Picture = requests.get(Original_URL, headers=Headers, stream=True)
            if Picture.status_code == 200:
                break
        if Picture.status_code != 200:
            return -1
        Filename = "./pic/"+str(Pixiv_ID) + "/"\
                   + str(Pixiv_ID) + "_p"\
                   + str(Number) + Picture_Type[i]
        Picture_File = open(Filename, "wb+")
        for chunk in Picture.iter_content(None):
            Picture_File.write(chunk)
        Picture_File.close()
        Picture.close()
    return 200


# Main function.
def get_pic(Pixiv_ID):
    Index_URL = "http://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?"\
                "mode=medium&illust_id="+str(Pixiv_ID)
    Headers = {'referer': Index_URL}
    Index_HTML = requests.get(Index_URL, headers=Headers, stream=True)
    if Index_HTML.status_code != 200:
        return Index_HTML.status_code
    Index_XML = etree.HTML(Index_HTML.content)
    Tag_a_href_List = Index_XML.xpath('/html/body'
                                      '/div[@id="wrapper"]'
                                      '/div[@class="newindex"]'
                                      '/div[@class="newindex-inner"]'
                                      '/div[@class="newindex-bg-container"]'
                                      '/div[@class="cool-work"]'
                                      '/div[@class="cool-work-main"]'
                                      '/div[@class="img-container"]'
                                      '/a/@href')
    Tag_img_src_List = Index_XML.xpath('/html/body'
                                       '/div[@id="wrapper"]'
                                       '/div[@class="newindex"]'
                                       '/div[@class="newindex-inner"]'
                                       '/div[@class="newindex-bg-container"]'
                                       '/div[@class="cool-work"]'
                                       '/div[@class="cool-work-main"]'
                                       '/div[@class="img-container"]'
                                       '/a/img/@src')
    if Tag_a_href_List == [] or Tag_img_src_List == []:
        return 404
    else:
        Tag_a_href = Tag_a_href_List[0]
        Tag_img_src = Tag_img_src_List[0]
    Index_HTML.close()
    if Tag_a_href.find("manga") != -1:
        return get_manga(Pixiv_ID, Tag_a_href, Tag_img_src, Headers)
    else:
        return get_single(Pixiv_ID, Tag_img_src, Headers)


# Check whether the picture already exists.
def check_exist(Pixiv_ID):
    if not os.path.isdir("Pic"):
        os.mkdir("Pic")
    if os.path.isdir("./Pic/"+str(Pixiv_ID)):
        return True
    Picture_Type = [".png", ".jpg", ".gif"]
    Picture_Exist = False
    for i in range(len(Picture_Type)):
        Path = "./Pic/" + str(Pixiv_ID)\
               + "_p0" + Picture_Type[i]
        if os.path.isfile(Path):
            return True
    return Picture_Exist


# The script starts here.
for i in range(0, 38849402):
    Pixiv_ID = 38849402-i
    Picture_Exist = check_exist(Pixiv_ID)
    if not Picture_Exist:
        Return_Code = get_pic(Pixiv_ID)
        if Return_Code == 200:
            print str(Pixiv_ID), "finish!"
        elif Return_Code == -1:
            print str(Pixiv_ID), "got an unknown error."
        elif Return_Code == 404:
            print str(Pixiv_ID), "not found. Maybe deleted."
    else:
        print str(Pixiv_ID), "picture exists!"
```

Comment: This is a bit too big of a mess to wade through, you should try memory_profiler. At first glance, it looks like you're reading the image in all at one time. Try writing a [MCVE] of this, if possible, it's difficult to follow with all the globals, non-standard naming, etc.

Comment: @pvg I have comment the variable and logic of my script. Is it clear enough now?

Comment: It doesn't help that much, try streaming the requests like `r = requests.get(url, stream=True)`. in `iter_content` set chunk_size to None because 5 is ridiculous.

Comment: @pvg Well, I really don't know how to make it clearer. Because I don't know which code causes such big usage, I have no choice but to paste all codes and comment the logic to help readers understand. So, any suggestions about how to edit?

Comment: Just try the things I told you above.

Comment: @pvg I have tried add "stream=True". It directly tells me "Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory" with 620M+ memory left after I started running.

Comment: @pvg And strangely, I found it only takes up only 20M memory  sometimes but 1.2G sometimes.

Comment: It's hard to tell what on earth you're getting from all these requests - the fact is, you always read in the whole thing and you never close most responses. You should fix that, systematically - you should not be making non-streaming requests at all unless you're absolutely sure the response is going to be short  and you should always close responses. Additionally, don't be passing 5 into iter_content. just don't pass anything into it at all.

Comment: @pvg Sorry to disturb you again. Today I have tried almost everything I can to reduce memory usage including adding "stream=true", "del variable", "gc.collect()" etc. But they all don't work at all. The memory is always 1.2G or 10M. I feel exhausted. Thank you all the same.

Comment: Did you make sure to close every response you get?

Comment: @pvg I have tried like `r=request.get('xxx")` and `r.close()`. But when I type `r.status_code` it sill returns a code and `r.content` also returns its content. It seems that `requests.close()` does nothing.

Comment: No, that doesn't mean that r.close does nothing. The fundamental problem is, this code is, I'm sorry to tell you, terrible. It's just impossible to easily read, and it's basically not python. Take a look at PEP 8. Use parameters and return values, not globals. Name things sanely - if a thing is a request response, don't call it 'url'. Don't capitalize everything. When you open a file or other resource, close it or use `with` or contextlib. Just take an hour or two to clean this mess up and then you (and others) might have an easier time looking at it.

Comment: @pvg Well, I am back after rewriting all my code to make it pass `pep8`. Still unclear?

Comment: Oh, that looks so very much better! (despite your unabiding love for capitals). I'll give it a whirl later today.

Comment: @pvg Finally, I solved the problem(see my answer below). Thank you all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMG!

Finally, I know what goes wrong.

I use `mem_top()` to see what takes up the memory.

Guess what?

It is `for i in range(0, 38849402):`

In the memory, there is a list [0, 1, 2, 3 ... 38849401], which takes up my memory.

I change it to :

```
Pixiv_ID = 38849402
while Pixiv_ID > 0:

    some code here

    Pixiv_ID = Pixiv_ID-1
```

Now the memory usage is just no more than 20M.

Feeling excited!

Comment: Aha! Outstanding. And that's yet another really, really good reason to switch to Python 3. But look at this code now, composed functions, actual html parser. Your suffering was not for naught.

Comment: Alternatively use `xrange`

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Killjoy.

Comment: @pvg Indeed, in order to reduce memory usage, I tried and learned a lot of things, which gives me a better understanding of Python.

Comment: `xrange` is also a nice solution. It also works well. Thanks. @ColonelThirtyTwo

Comment: Entertainingly, the reason I couldn't reproduce your results was because I chopped off the range so the thing would complete a run through the profiler in a not-17-weeks-time. Doh!